# Cannot submit user input value from text field , getting null in action class

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a input field in a form named feedback. I need to submit feedback and store it in database. But I am getting input value as null and empty string is getting stored.

Javascript for submitting file

```
function submitKdApproval(user,teamId)
{   
    //alert("ok");
    document.getElementById("user1").value=user;
    document.getElementById("teamId1").value=teamId;
    document.forms["submitKdApprovalForm"].action ="submitKdApproval.do?go=submitKdApproval";
    document.forms["submitKdApprovalForm"].submit();
}
```

Inside action class

```
String feedback=(String)request.getParameter("feedback");
```

This line is giving me a null string. Please help

Here is part of my html.

```
<html:form action='/submitKdApproval.do' styleId='submitKdApprovalForm' >    
<input type="text" name="feedback" id="feedback" name="feedback" />

<input type="hidden" id="user1" name="user1" value='${knowledgeDashboardVO.user}'/>
 <input type="hidden" id="teamId1" name="teamId1" value='${knowledgeDashboardVO.teamId}'/>
</html:form>
```

Comment: where are you sending the value of feedback from your view to action?

Comment: I have used Form class to get and set the data. I am using Struts 1.1